# Is there a fast way to get the column letter from a Range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

As you can see in the following code, my way of creating this specific range to copy, is quite extensive. Is there a more efficient way?

```
    For counter = 1 To quantity
    
        Set header_range(counter) = _
        Application.InputBox("Select the HEADER of the " & counter & "º column you want to copy", Type:=8)
        
        col_number = header_range(counter).Column
        last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, col_number).End(xlUp).Row
        col_letter = Split(Cells(1, col_number).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

        Range(header_range(counter), Range(col_letter & last_row)).Copy
        
        target_wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, counter).PasteSpecial
        
    Next counter
```

Comment: Use `Cells( Row Number, Column Number )` so you don't need the letter at all. Just use shorter variables for `header_range` & `last_row` like ( `r` & `c` )

Comment: Not exactly sure you want you are trying to do though. Are you sure you want the inputbox inside the loop? Will the target header change for every value of `quantity`? If not, you should move that outside the loop. May be good to explain more context of the problem :)

Comment: Using the letter is clunky. Use `Cells` as already recommended with the row and column indices.

Comment: I usually use `cells()` but in this case I needed to use the `InputBox` with selection because the person who uses the sheet wanted it that way. And this input comes in the `range()` format.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the text of the question. For example, what if you have a `Range` and you want the letter-number style cell reference for use in a formula? To get the letter-number cell reference however, you can use the [`Address()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) method of the `Range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the actual letter. Instead, use the Column & Row Index with the `Cells` object. The `Cells` inputs are indexes *i.e.* `Cells(Row Index, Column Index)`. I would also recommend shorter variable names for readability

- `r` = Row Index
- `c` = Column Index

---

Here is an example of using the indexes to copy the range from `Row 1` to `r` (*last row*) in the variable column selected via the `InputBox`

```
Sub Example()

Dim Input_C As Range
Dim r As Long, c As Long

Set Input_C = Application.InputBox("Select Target Header", Type:=8)

'Convert to Index
c = Input_C.Column
r = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row

'Build Dynamic Range
Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(r, c)).Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: That's awesome. You don't need to get the letter. Thanks!

Comment: Wrote this up in a rush before hoping on a meeting. Updated with explanation. In prod, you should also qualify all objects (`Range`, `Cells`, etc.) with a worksheet object.

Comment: I liked your suggestion for the shorter variable names.